# Receiving text from other apps via Share menu

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm writing a language dictionary app for myself (as a kind of Android-programming learning exercise).

I want my app to be listed as an option in the intent chooser of other apps, so I add these code lines to my manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```

My app successfully appears in the action menu of other apps (e.g. Browser), which is good. My app is also successfully called via Share when I choose it from Browser action menu.

Now I want my app to receive and process text (a word) sent from other apps, and then automatically look the text up for its definition. I add the following code lines to the main activity of my app:

```
//(under onCreate)
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();
            EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edWord);

            if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
                if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {

                    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                    if (sharedText != null) {                        
                          edittext.setText(sharedText);
                    }
                }
            }
```

However at this stage, Browser gets crashed every time my app is chosen from the action menu via Share.

So it comes to my questions:

1. **What have I done wrong?**
2. **How/What could I do to "force" my app to accept text
   from other apps, and automatically display its definition?**

Sorry for these are noobie questions (my headache, though).

Thank you very much for your help.

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks, CommonWare. Nothing is produced when Browser is crashed but when I choose "Share" from  the web view of my app, I get this log cat:

```
08-09 18:17:23.726: W/dalvikvm(1111): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8) 
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111): FATAL EXCEPTION: main   
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{peter.kadict/peter.kadict.Kadict}: java.lang.NullPointerException    
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at peter.kadict.Kadict.onCreate(Kadict.java:449)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
08-09 18:17:23.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     ... 11 more
```

**UPDATE 2**

This code has solved the problem thanks to **CommonsWare**.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();               

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {

            String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

            if (sharedText != null) {
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edWord);
                    edittext.setText(sharedText);
                }
        }     
    }
```

But it does not do its task: the app is loaded but does not seem to receive and process the text (word) sent from other apps.

Can you you guys help? Many thanks.

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks a lot. Please have a look at my update.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException --> Kadict.java line 449. Should be straight enough, what's on that line?

Comment: Yup post code at Line No:449 of file Kadict.java

Comment: Absolutely, at Line No:449. It is `edittext.setText(sharedText);` as shown in the above code. But what's wrong with it? Many thanks.

Comment: Hey friend, just **confirm**, Line No:449. It is edittext.setText(sharedText);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

- You have not called `setContentView()`, or
- You do not have an `EditText` widget with an `android:id` of `@+id/edWord`, or
- Clean your project (e.g., Project > Clean from the Eclipse main menu) and try it again

Comment: Thank you very much. `setContentView()` does the trick! Please have a look at Update 2. Now there are no error messages and my app is successfully called from Browser via Share. However, another problem emerges: only the Main Activity is called - no text in the EditText box (edWord) - no text is looked up. Have you got any clues for that?

Comment: @NiamhDoyle: No, sorry. Use breakpoints or logging to determine what portions of the code that you are going through.

Answer (score 1):

So i got the same problem and i dont know what is wrong with the activities so i solved the problem by getting the shared text and put it in a bundle to a new intent to do what ever i want with it

here is my code

```
public class GetFromShared extends Activity {
    TextView tex;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {

                String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                Log.d("Shared text is", sharedText);

                Intent rooy = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        BayenELText.class);

                rooy.putExtra("GotText", sharedText);
                startActivity(rooy);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

and receiving class is

```
public class BayenELText extends Activity {
    TextView blabla;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getsharedtext);
        blabla = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etSharedText);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        String hloho = extras.getString("GotText");
        blabla.setText(hloho);

    }
}
```

the log shows the shared text when it called from share via but the thing i thought of that the Intent filter when it called by

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
```

doesn't have the permmision to make any changes to the view so that how i solve it and it works fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

When I see this logcat output, I immediately think about the fact that the activity cannot be found. If that is the case, a NPE will be thrown.

So:
1. Do you have the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml ?
2. Is it possible to start the activity yourself using `adb shell am start -n peter.kadict/peter.kadict.Kadict` ?

Comment: I don't think that it is not getting Activity. The error NullPointerException is due to some other reasons.

Comment: @Jordi: Thank you. 1. Yes, I have this <activity android:name="peter.kadict.Kadict"></activity> in my manifest - 2. Yes, it does. My app is loaded after this command.